# How to properly prepare JsonWebKey for API request?

Tags: c#, json, rsa

```
{
"client_name": "apk1",
"scopes": [
    "full"
],
"jwks": {
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "use": "sig",
            "kid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "alg": "RS512",
            "n": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}}
```

Api expects such json. Can anyone advise me on how to properly deliver jwks? I tried to use the JsonWebKey class but I have no idea how to get the structure like above in json.

```
 var client = new RestClient("url");
        var request = new RestRequest("/auth/token", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Authtoken);

        RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
        var rs256 = new RS256Algorithm(rsa, rsa);

        //var token = GenerateToken(1);

        RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);
        var parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
        var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(parameters);
        var jwk = JsonWebKeyConverter.ConvertFromRSASecurityKey(rsaSecurityKey);

        request.AddJsonBody(new
        {
            client_name = "client_name",
            scopes = new[] { "full" },
            jwks = new { keys = new[] { jwk } }
        });

        var TaskResponse = client.ExecutePostAsync<CreateClientResponse>(request);
        TaskResponse.Wait();
```

Comment: You probably need to serialise `jwk` manually before sending it into the post body.

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: jwk is not serialized to json as in the example.
It has many more fields. I will probably have to do as DavidG said. Though hopefully there is some good practice. On this page you can generate json exactly as it needs https://mkjwk.org/ but how to do it in c #?

Comment: If you need to self-serialize the class, you have to write a converter for it. Because [RestSharp uses System.Text.Json](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#json) you could create your own converter for `JsonWebKey` and add it to the converters within the serializer options.

Comment: You should be able to simply project the fields you need. See if it works if you : `keys = new[] { new { jwk.kty, jwt.e, etc...} } ...`